# How to write a shell script which will execute commands of root and which should work for both Fedora and Ubuntu

Tags: linux, shell

I am writing a shell script which will execute few commands as a super user,

```
sudo -s <<EOF
rm -r /opt/staging_dir/
cp -r staging_dir /opt/
EOF
```

Above script is working properly for Ubuntu but its not happening in case of Fedora?

Is there any way to write a common script for both.?

Also how to find type of OS using shell script?

for Ex:

if my OS is Ubuntu then do step 1

else do step 2.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: `lsb_release -si` will give you the OS. So to assign it to a variable, you can use `OS = $(lsb_release -si)`.

Comment: Thanks, @PoojaNilangekar  What about the first question can you help in that?

Comment: Sorry no clue about the first question!

Comment: What about this isn't working on Fedora? And `lsb_release` is not entirely reliable (it requires that command to exist, etc.).